# PHP regex conditional get content and link from HTML anchor tag

Tags: php, regex

I am trying getting the all anchor tags from a given HTML **where the content length is more then 30 chars** i.e. if i have this HTML with me

```
<td><a hreh="anything">Content is more then 30 chars........</a>
<a hreh="anything">another link</a>
</td>
```

I have write this RegEx for this `preg_match_all("/<a href=\"(.*)\"[^>]*>([a-zA-Z0-9]{30,999})<\\/[a-zA-Z]+>/si",
            $match[0],$posts);`

where 30 is putting the limit of minimum 30 char to anchor tag content but unfortunately this is not working.

Anyone out there who can point out what i have made wrong.

Thanks

Note : I am trying fetching this page URL's
[This Link](http://tzforums.timezone.com/search/index.php/?q2=For+sale+rolex&f=71&t=1&s=0&max=1000&ra=1)

Comment: `[a-zA-Z0-9]` this as you see will only match letters and digits and as far as I know URLs contain a little more than that `:P`

Comment: Is the content really just letters and numbers, no spaces or punctuation?

Comment: @php_nub_qq He's not using that to match the URL, it's the text of the link.

Comment: @php-nub-qq this is for text within the anchor tag.<a>(here)</a>

Comment: @Barmar Yes spaces are there.

Comment: You need to allow spaces as well then

Comment: I have tried with this too ([a-zA-Z0-9,\s]?)

Comment: It's as simple as `[a-zA-Z0-9 ]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would something simple as

```
<a.*?>.{30,}?</a>
```

not suffice?  The above looks for anchor tags, with their content being 30 characters or more.  It does not attempt to validate the href attribute or any other attributes of the link.  It can be altered if these are required.

This is translated into `preg_match_all` as (thanks to @php_nub_qq)

```
preg_match_all("#<a.*?>.{30,}?</a>#", $match[0],$posts);
```

The URL you have linked contains letters, numbers, and non-alphanumeric characters in the url string.  As you have little control over the source, it might be best to generalise the case like above rather than attempt to white list on a per character basis.

Comment: Actually you would want that to be `<a.*?>.{30,}?</a>`

Comment: @php_nub_qq why the extra `>`?

Comment: Because otherwise it wont stop at the first occurance of `</a>`

Comment: @php_nub_qq i have used preg_match_all("<a.*?>.{30,}?</a>", $match[0],$posts); and i got this Warning: preg_match_all(): Unknown modifier '.' I have PHP: 5.4.16

Comment: @ravisoni you may need to escape the `/`. I have amended the pattern.  I do not have php here to test to confirm however.

Comment: @ravisoni `preg_match_all("#<a.*?>.{30,}?</a>#", $match[0],$posts);`

Comment: But I discourage this method because I tested it and it gave me unexpected results.

Comment: @php_nub_qq Thanks please post your RegEx as asnwer this solved my porblem

Comment: @ravisoni It isn't mine, Kami came up with it `:P`

Comment: @php_nub_qq I am not familiar with the usage of `preg_match_all`.  Are the `#` symbols used as delimiters to identify the pattern? is this required for `preg_match_all`?

Comment: Yes, in php regex requires delimiters, people usually use `/` but I don't like it because you will often find it in subject strings and it may mess things up and cause you to lose a lot of time before realizing what is actually going on, but again that is my humble opinion `:D`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
preg_match_all("/<a href=\"(.*)\"[^>]*>([a-z\d\s]{30,})<\\/[a-z]+>/si", $match[0],$posts);
```

Since you have the `i` case-insensitive modifier, you don't need both `a-z` and `A-Z` in your classes. And if you're just setting a minimum length of the content, you don't need to specify a maximum of `999`; `{30,}` means 30 or more.